How can I have a dynamic number of InputForms that grows as I add to it?
I'm trying to write a program where it starts with one input field, and if I fill out that input field, then another input field gets added below the first one and if I fill that one out another appears below that, etc. I'd like to have a list that dynamically shows what's in the input fields. Having some trouble implementing this. I imagine this would use InputField in some way. Anyone have an idea how to get it to work? Thanks.

What does it mean to 'fill out an input field'? Also, closely related: 1199
